# Problema configuracion IIS y SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

Tengo que migrar una aplicación de un servidor a otro. He clonado la base de datos en SQL Server e instalado la aplicación en el nuevo servidor IIS.

Se trata de una aplicación asp.net y ya he cambiando en el webconfig la cadena de conexión con el nuevo servidor. El problema es que si lanzo la aplicación en el nuevo servidor, no me realiza el login correctamente cuando introduzco las credenciales. No llega a entrar. Es como si no estuviera bien hecho la migración.

Se os ocurre alguna cosa que hacer que haya que hacer. Es la primera vez que migro una aplicación y estoy un poco perdido.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Está en ejecución SQL en el Servidor?

Comment: Podrias anexar fotos de el error o lo que te genera al intentar hacer el login, a ver si depronto es un error mas intuitivo

Comment: Hola. Es que no genera ningún error. A veces aparece un loader por defecto, pero al pasar 10 segundos se va, y luego la página queda normal. No da ningún error. Gracias.

Comment: En el Windows Server, si entro en el Sql Management Studio la base de datos está activada. Lo que no sé es si desde el gestor de IIS hay que añadir alguna cosa o  que. La base de datos ya me la dejaron funcionando, en mi webconfig, en la cadena de conexión tengo un usuario y contraseña, lo que no sé, es si necesito en SQL Server Management crearme un usario con los credenciales del webconfig. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y que tipo de aplicacion tienes?. Usa sql management para verificar que el nuevo servidor sql este ejecutando y accede a el con las credenciales que usa la aplicacion para conectarse con esa BD

Comment: Es un registro de pacientes, donde el médico rellena los formularios. Un CRUD básicamente. Conectado estoy, hay un usuario Administrator que puede entrar en todas las tablas, pero luego si cuando me conecto con los credenciales del Webconfig, en Authentication y seleccionar SQL Server Authentication, tras meter los credenciales me permite entrar. Sin embargo, si trato de acceder a cualquiera de las tablas, me dice "The database  XXX is not accesible (Object Explore)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que mirar si tienes el usuario de conexión en la base de datos. Si no lo tienes ejecutas el create User para tu login.

Y luego le añades al esquema que quieras que funcione. (normalmente dbo = propietario de la bbdd)

```
USE [tubase]
GO
CREATE USER [nameUser] FOR LOGIN [nameUser]
GO
USE [tubase]
GO
ALTER USER [tubase] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Esto debería de ser suficiente.

Realizando esto desde el SQL Server Management Studio, sobre todo en versiones 2012 R2 y anteriores, requiere de un paso adicional.

[image: Crear un nuevo inicio de sesión]

Si el inicio ya existe, entonces lo buscamos de entre los elementos y lo abrimos.

[image: General]

En la primera página de los inicios de sesión, si es nuevo cubrimos la información, pero si es una modificación no hacemos nada.

Página de Asignación de usuarios. Si es una modificación, la opción más simple, es eliminar el usuario de la base de datos ya existente. Porque el inicio de sesión va a intentar crearlo. En el árbol del explorador de objetos, Bases de datos (+), dentro de nuestra base de datos (+), Seguridad (+), Usuarios (+) y en la lista, eliminamos el mismo seleccionando el usuario y botón derecho eliminar. 
Adicional: si es propietario de algún rol, no te dejará eliminarlo, primero tendrás que asignar el rol a otro propietario (por ejemplo dbo), para poder eliminarlo.

[image: Asignación de usuarios]

Aceptas y te genera el nuevo inicio de sesión. Luego otra vez en el explorador de objetos, al nivel de inicios de sesión, pulsas botón derecho actualizar. Y **repites** abriendo el inicio de sesión la **Asignación de usuarios**. Al entrar en el mismo, observarás que si seleccionas tu base de datos, el db_owner, no estaba marcado.

Comment: Lo probé, crea el nuevo usuario, pero sigue sin entrar en la base de datos. Te agradezco mucha la idea. Yo también creo que el problema va por ahí.

Comment: Voy a modificar la respuesta, para hacerlo desde el Management Studio. En Sql server 2014 o anteriores (no recuerdo seguro si 2014 era o era en 2012 r2), había que actualizar la conexión.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta en el IIS, la configuracion del usuario que necesita la aplicacion para ejecutarse, si usa un usuario impersonalizado o uno con los suficientes permisos de lectura al folder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como se podría configurar en el IIS podrías agregar más información? como se le darían permisos? revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: He adjuntado la foto.